# warning: 'long_opts' may be used uninitialised in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialised]

Tags: c, gcc

So I've been given this code that I'm supposed to work into my code which reads options from the command line using the `getopt_long()` function and passes them through a switch menu. The problem lies in that function, whereby if I don't initialise the value of `long_opts` I receive the following error:

> `error: 'long_opts' undeclared (first use in this function)`

whereas if I do indeed initialise its value, I receive the error in the title:

> `warning: 'long_opts' may be used uninitialised in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialised]`

At the moment I'm wondering what the lesser of two evils might be because I absolutely cannot find a solution.

Comment: show your code perhaps? maybe you init your variable only in one stream of a branch?

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: Show your code and think twice about the difference of declaration and initialization.

Comment: You *have* read the [manual page for e.g. `getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) (and `getopt_long`)? They have good examples on how to use the `getopt` (and `getopt_long` function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using an uninitialized structure, then initialize it like this:

`static struct option long_options[] = {
    {"add",     required_argument, 0,  0 },
    {"append",  no_argument,       0,  0 },
    {"delete",  required_argument, 0,  0 },
    {"verbose", no_argument,       0,  0 },
    {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
    {"file",    required_argument, 0,  0 },
    {0,         0,                 0,  0 }
};`

show your code please

error: 'long_opts' undeclared

this error appears if you are not declare a variable and use it in function.

warning: 'long_opts' may be used uninitialised in this function

this is not error, it is "warning" and this warning appears if you are declare var or struct, but do not initialize it and try to use it in function or expression but value of these var or struct is not define